# Enumerator.Current is null but collection has data. What am I doing wrong

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, enumeration

I have a dctionary and I am calling .GetEnumerator(); and assigning it to a variable. I am then using the newly assigned variable to access my dictionary and changing the value. However it is null and is giving me a NullException message. See code below:

**This is how my dictionary is created**

```
public Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string> GenerateTable(int _x, int _y)
{
    int total = _x * _y;
    var grid = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>(); //!Might need this later!

    for (int i = 1; i <= _x; i++) // outer loop is column 
    {
        for (int ii = 1; ii <= _y; ii++) // Inner loop is row -
        {
            grid.Add(Tuple.Create(i, ii), "O");
        }
    }
    return grid; // Should have same amount of elements as int total
}
```

**This is my code where I call .GetEnumerator**

```
 public void ClearTable(Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string> _table)
        {
            var e = _table.GetEnumerator();
            _table[e.Current.Key] = "O";
        }
```

**I get a null reference here**

```
_table[e.Current.Key] = "O";
```

I am sure this code was working before but maybe I changed it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

Enumerators start *one before* the first element of the enumerable. You need to call `MoveNext` first before accessing `Current`.

- If `MoveNext` returns true, the enumerable is non-empty and the enumerator now points to the first element.
- If `MoveNext` returns false, the enumerable is empty and you can't access `Current`.

## Example

```
IEnumerator<int> e = Enumerable.Range(4, 2).GetEnumerator();
// You may not access Current here! Enumerator is one before first element.
e.MoveNext(); //returns true
e.Current;    //returns 4
e.MoveNext(); //returns true
e.Current;    //returns 5
e.MoveNext(); //returns false
// You may not access Current here! Enumerator is one after last element.
```

Comment: Is it possible to write this code in a do/while loop? Editing the dictionary while it's enumerating is my problem. I don't know a good way to implement my code.

Comment: @nickgowdy What are you trying to do?